# phpenvやphp-buildを本番環境の構築に使っても構わないでしょうか？

Tags: php

現在所属する企業が、PHPのコミュニティと情報が隔絶しているWeb開発会社であり（←改善中）、そういう状況下で、PHPプログラマではないシステム管理者が本番環境のLinuxサーバ構築を行うという前提のお話になります。

上記前提で私は`phpenv`／`php-build`でビルドオプションに`--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs`を付与してグローバルインストールを行い、**ディストリビューション管理から切り離して運用するのが安全であろうと判断**して、`Vagrant`によるローカル環境に適用しています。しかし、`phpenv`での本番環境運用の事例を目にしないので、不安を感じています。

先日開催されたPHPカンファレンス2015にも参加したところ、PHPのバージョン問題は取り上げられていたものの、**PHPのインストール方法**についてはユーザ間では既知のものとされているのか、特に目立った取り上げ方がされていないような印象でした。

つきましては、PHPでWeb開発を行っている企業では、本番環境の構築でPHPのインストールはどうしているか、お聞きしたいです。

まとめると：

- `phpenv`／`php-build`によるPHPインストールは本番運用に耐えうるか
- 他にどういうインストール手段があるのか
- PHPで業務をしてる企業では実際にはPHPのインストールをどうしているのか

教えていただければありがたいです。

Comment: ディストリビューション管理から切り離した理由がよく分かりません。提供されるセキュリティパッチを適用すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @yhata さん： 一例としては、

[PHPのDoS脆弱性(CVE-2015-4024)キツくない？ - 出張おはき゛ろく](http://hakaikosen.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/05/30/204358)

にある``CVE-2015-4024``の適用が1か月半、PHP 5.3（ディストリビュータによるバックポートパッチでの適用）は2か月弱遅れになった件があります。

そこまで神経質になることもない、というのも意見のひとつかと思いますので、いろんな意見をうかがい、いい落としどころを見つけられればと思います。

Comment: 既にサポートが切れているPHP5.3に対するパッチのバックポートが遅いことを気にされるなら、パッチを**自己責任でバックポート**することになりますが・・・。

Comment: @unarist 今回のCVE-2015-4024の件で考えたのは、PHP 5.3はともかく、PHP 5.5や当時まだサポートされていたPHP 5.4の場合でも、ディストリビューションパッケージの更新が公式のPHPよりも遅かったため、脆弱性対応の面では公式PHPを利用する``php-build``のほうがディストリビューション管理よりも安全なのではないかと判断しました。もちろん、脆弱性に対応できるとしても、メンテナンス性に問題があったり、実用に耐えられないというのであれば、総合的に見てディストリビューションパッケージの利用のほうが安全という評価になると思います。その点、先行してシステムを運用されている皆さんにご意見を伺いたいです。

Answer (score 1):

「本番環境」であれば第一選択はディストリビューションで提供されるパッケージを使うことです。開発もそれをターゲットに行うべきです。

(･･･で、この本番環境がいろいろあるのでそれに合わせて複数の実行環境を簡単に切り替えられたらいいな、というのが*-envでしょう)

独自でビルドするのであれば、セキュリティアップデートへのタイムリーな追随と、バージョンアップによる非互換対策(検証と対応)の両方を検討しなければなりません。ディストリビューションが提供するパッケージはセキュリティパッチのバックポートという形で更新されていますので、後者の負担は大きく減ります。もちろんサポートの問題もあります。

> - phpenv／php-buildによるPHPインストールは本番運用に耐えうるか

運用方法次第でしょう

> - 他にどういうインストール手段があるのか

「ソースからインストールするかパッケージからインストールするか」という観点では2種類ですが、「ソースからインストールする」のバリエーションはいくらでも考えられます。

> - PHPで業務をしてる企業では実際にはPHPのインストールをどうしているのか

環境次第でしょう。

と、これらは正解がなく主観的な回答ばかりがあつまる質問なのであまり好ましい形式の質問ではありません。的確な答えを得るためには、[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)やその中の[質問に当たって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) 等を確認して、質問を改善してください

---

質問の改善方向としては、コメントで「ディストリビューションのパッケージではセキュリティアップデートが遅い場合がある」とありますが、「そのような遅れは許されずセキュリティアップデートは例外なく迅速に適用されなければならない」という要件があるのであればそれを説明すれば良いのです。

他にもあなたの頭の中にしか無い要件がいくらでもあるのではないですか？具体的な要件が示せれば良い質問になるでしょう。

求められていること自分で説明しきれないのに「雑多な意見」から正解が得られると思っているならそれは多分幻想です。SOの評価システムはなんの助けにもなりません。それよりも能力のあるコンサルタントにコンサルティングを受けることをお勧めします。彼らの能力のほとんどは｢正解そのもの」の知識では無く、顧客が説明しきれない曖昧模糊とした条件を具体的にするところにあります。

Comment: 今回の質問に関して、「好ましい形式の質問ではない」というご指摘ですが、PHPのインストールのトピックというだけで10数年の間に様々な情報が出回っているわけで、私も10数年前TurboLinuxにPHPを入れる際、参照した情報がよくなかったため、``mbstring``の不足による謎の不具合が生じ、PHP環境でのサービス構築を断念したという経験があります。このように、あちこちにある情報に対し目利きがよくないために環境構築ができないという問題があるなあと感じており、この場で質問させていただいたので、どうにかお目こぼしをいただければと思います。後学の方のために混乱しないよう、質問タイトルに「2015」と年号をつけて、情報選抜の助けになるように工夫をしました。また、このサイトでは回答にスコアリングができるとのことで、主観による回答であっても参考になる回答を評価できるのではないかと思います。

Comment: @CLCL 仮に後々同じようなQ&Aが現れるならこの質問・回答を更新すればいいでしょうし、情報の鮮度が重要になるのは質問より回答ですから、質問タイトルに年を書くメリットは薄いと思います。のでタイトルから取り除きました。

Comment: @unarist もともとは **「PHP本体のインストール・ビルド・バージョン管理について」** という質問タイトルでしたが、その後、私が「PHP本体のインストール・ビルド・バージョン管理について **（2015年）** 」というタイトルに変更したあと、上記の判断があり、unaristさんに **「phpenvやphp-buildを本番環境の構築に使っても構わないでしょうか？」** というタイトルに変更していただいたという経緯があるということを記録しておきます。
私としては、実用環境（本番環境）をどのように構築しているかアドバイスをいただきたいというのが主たる目的でしたが、変更していただいたタイトルどおり、phpenvやphp-buildの実用性の知見を確認してから当方の作業手順を見直すのもあるなあと思いましたので、変更後のタイトルでもかまいません。適切なタイトルを考えていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @CLCL 「○○について」は質問内容がわかりにくいという点、ソースからのビルドも示す具体的なキーワードを入れることで、よりこの質問に興味を持つ人が現れるのでは、と思っての変更でした。が、ちょっとやりすぎだったかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

質問のタイトルが途中で変更となっていますので適切ではないかもしれませんが、元の質問の中での「他にどういうインストール手段があるのか」としていたものですから、その後、いろいろ調べて得られた情報を書き込みます。

**CentOS 6**では、「その他」のPHPインストール手段として、

- Webデザイン系のところは、`Remi (Remi's RPM repository)`
- エンプラ系のでは、`SCL (Software Collections for CentOS 6)`

を使うことができるようです。

年度をタイトルに書くのは良くないということで、2016年初頭時点での話としてこちらに書きますが、

`Remi`に関しては2012年ごろからすでにWeb上で利用されている様子があり、こちらにPHPの新しいバージョンのRPMが収録されているということで、Webデザインをやられている方を中心に現時点の2016年頭に至るまで利用されているように見受けられます。

`SCL`は、2013年にRedhatがリリースしたRedhat Software CollectionsのCentOS 6用で、私の観測範囲ではPHPの新バージョンインストールのためのものという情報が発見できなかったのですが、2016年3月、Zabbix 3.0アップグレードでPHP 5.3サポート切り捨てとなった際の代替手段として「SCLなどを利用」と提示していたことで知ることが出来ました。see also: http://www.slideshare.net/atanaka7/zabbix30

個人的には、これらを使っている方のご意見も聞きたいところです。